# Could this scoped thread code be changed to use `FnOnce()` instead of `Box<FnOnce()>`?

Tags: rust

I have the following code that implements scoped threads in Rust - that is, the ability to spawn threads and safely access variables that are on the stack. Most of the following code is taken from [crossbeam](https://github.com/aturon/crossbeam), with a bit of inspiration also from [scoped_threadpool](https://github.com/Kimundi/scoped-threadpool-rs).

```
use std::thread;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::collections::LinkedList;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::boxed::Box;

pub struct Scope<'a> {
    join_handles: LinkedList<JoinHandle<()>>,
    _marker: PhantomData<::std::cell::Cell<&'a mut ()>>
}

impl<'a> Scope<'a> {
    pub fn spawn<F>(&mut self, f: F) where F: FnOnce() + Send + 'a {
        // Could this be done without using a Box?
        let closure: Box<FnBox + Send + 'a> = Box::new(f);
        let closure: Box<FnBox + Send + 'static> = unsafe{
            std::mem::transmute(closure)
        };
        let join_handle = thread::spawn(move || closure.call_box());
        self.join_handles.push_back(join_handle);
    }
}

pub fn scope<'a, F, R>(f: F) -> R where F: FnOnce(&mut Scope<'a>) ->     R {
    let mut scope = Scope {
        join_handles: LinkedList::new(),
        _marker: PhantomData
    };
    let ret = f(&mut scope);
    for join_handle in scope.join_handles {
        join_handle.join().unwrap();
    }
    ret
}

trait FnBox {
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>);
}

impl<F: FnOnce()> FnBox for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>) { (*self)() }
}

// Example usage:

// let mut foo = 0;
// scope(|mut scope| {
//     scope.spawn(|| {
//         foo = 1;
//     });
// });
// assert!(foo == 1);
```

Could the `spawn` function be changed so that `f` is not placed in a `Box`, in order to avoid the extra heap allocation? If not, why is it necessary to use a `Box`?

Comment: I think the reason the `Box` is necessary is that `mem::transmute<T,U>` needs to check that the size of types `T` and `U` are equal, and in order to do that `T` and `U` must be `Sized`. `F` is not `Sized`, but `Box<F>` is.

Comment: So if Rust had an `expand_lifetime` function that worked on `?Sized` types, it would be possible, right? Something like `fn expand_lifetime<'a, T: ?Sized>(x: T + 'a) -> T + 'static`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible as of Rust 1.12. We'd have to transmute `f` into another type of the same size that respects the `'static` bound. The most straightforward way to do this would be to convert it into an array of bytes of the same size as `F`, but that's not possible because we can't use [`size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) in a constant expression (as we could with `sizeof` in C++).

We could work around this by allocating an array with a fixed size that is independent from `F` and either panic if `F` is too large or fall back to using `Box`.

```
impl<'a> Scope<'a> {
    pub fn spawn<F>(&mut self, f: F) where F: FnOnce() + Send + 'a {
        assert!(std::mem::size_of::<F>() <= 256);
        let mut x: [u8; 256] = [0; 256];
        unsafe { std::ptr::write(&mut x as *mut _ as *mut F, f); }
        let join_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let f: F = unsafe { std::mem::transmute_copy(&x) };
            f()
        });
        self.join_handles.push_back(join_handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting to think about what would be needed to do this in a "clean" manner. Ideally, you could `transmute` from `F` to `F-prime`, where the latter has had all its lifetimes substituted with `'static`. Of course, there's no way to pick apart the type of `F` or to put it back together again. The boxed trait object allows the code to specify *a* type that it can then control the lifetimes of.